# Toggle between two modal windows

Tags: modal-windows, modal, share

I have a system where a user can share a task with his coworkers.
The system was developed in a way where the share button opens a modal dialog with the option to input details of the user to share it with.
If you click the number to the side of the share button, it will open a different modal dialog with the history of people the task was shared with.

I want to improve this flow to make the sharing process easier.
I want to let the users switch between the two modals in an easy frictionless way, without damaging the current workflow.

Key points:

- make the workflow faster and easier.
- maintain the current solution.
- do not get into a big development project.

Here is an illustration of the current process:

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I think you should have one modal **Share** one.

Below 'Share' model, give a link ***See who already shared*** and one click of it display the next Shared List. Simple.

Comment: If this answers your question, please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Good use case to look at is Google Drive/Google Docs. This is this share screen:

[image: Google Drive sharing]

All the information is present right in the same modal. One caveat, you have to click through to get the full list. Your options here are, based on what the requirements are:

- Place a scrollable list below the form in the case where is it vital to have quick access to the list.
- Make a clickable *and others* link that expands into a full list in the case the information is not necessarily needed now.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this situation once, and it was solved by combining two modals into one with 2 tabs.  For example, if you click "Share" button, a modal launches with "Share" tab selected.  If you click history button, a modal launches with history tab selected as default.

The only challenge in your case is, size of the modals are very different.  However, you can remedy it by showing the Email and Name fields side-by-side, and vary height of the modal depending on which tab is selected.